# How can I increase high wealth tourism?

Tags: simcity-2013

I am developing a tourism focused city. The population is around 80,000. It currently has the following amenities:

- Pro Stadium
- Arc d'Triumphe
- Empire State Building

There is plenty of mass transit in and out of the city, including both regional and shuttle bus stations, streetcar stations, 2 train stations, a ferry/cruise ship terminal, and a municipal airport with 2 runways and 2 passenger terminals. By and large, traffic is not a problem, and all the above stations have plenty of tourists arriving daily. There are also lots of hotel options for low and medium wealth sims, and a couple hi-rise hotels for high wealth sims as well as shopping for each class.

Routinely, in my pro stadium, I host the "world championship" event in hopes of attracting more medium and high wealth tourists. The event is very profitable each time (though never totally full) but is frequented by mostly low wealth tourists, with a decent showing of medium wealth tourists but maybe just 10 or so high wealth tourists. There is also low high wealth attendance at the arc and empire state building.

What am I missing here? **How can I attract more high wealth sims to my city and the stadium events?**

Comment: Maybe this article could help you somehow? It's worth reading. http://www.ea.com/uk/news/simcity-wealth

Comment: Have you tried an airport?

Comment: I have a muncipal airport with 2 runways and 2 passenger terminals already. No international airport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is based on my own experince.

I myself made sure to have several other citys in the region.
A few of these cities are based on High-wealth population.

In these cities, I then made sure to have the same means of transportation I have in the city that is based on tourism.
Having my "High-wealth" cities reaching a population of >100.000, gave my a significant boost to tourism. (not saying that 100.000 pop. is the key)

My Casinos and Landmarks are running like a well oiled engine.
Making it possible to lower taxes for the general pop. = increasing happiness!

The Masstransit that I use:
- Airport
- Trains
- Busses (regional)
All of these are placed in all of my cities!

Comment: I've found that placing a Ferry Terminal and adding a cruise ship terminal helps enormously with attracting high wealth tourists. One day I had around 300 tourists with only one small attraction, all low-medium. That day I added a terminal and Elegant Casino, the next day I had 1,250 tourists come in through the terminal, 90% of which were high wealth. This of course requires water around your city, however.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this problem last night. I was struggling to get a high wealth tourist in my town until I started zoning High Wealth Commercial buildings.

Kinda makes sense. In your point of view, if you're very wealthy, would you visit vegas if there are no high-end shopping places around? I don't think you'll just go there to gamble all night. I'd go to effing strip clubs, malls, expensive restaurant and stuff just to blow all my money.

My point is, zone damn commercial structures with high land value ($$$) and that should attract high wealth tourist. When you get 4 tall buildings that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

once you have a lot of tourists you can destroy the hotels from your casinos and build modules to increase capacity. this is what i have done and i now make around 400k to 500k per casino and this earns me around 120k/h